# Why databases employ B plus tree for indexing?

Tags: database, tree

For the purpose of fast searching, insertion and deletion the nodes in index we could use Red-blue tree, but B-plus tree is employed instead.
Why ?

Comment: when all operation are in memory use other data structure may be more efficient，but as a database the more operation need disk IO，so B+ tree is more efficient，you can learn how operate disk IO，it can help you understand this.